# Change histogram to curve in Matlab but not "fit"

Tags: matlab

I am using matlab to process data to get a radius distribution function. Now I get data(an array) of different distances of other atoms to 1 specific atom.
I used the "hist" command (hist(radius1,400)) and get a histogram:

But what I want is a curve, like this:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Lennard-Jones_Radial_Distribution_Function.svg

I tried some fit command, but it would give me a normal-distribution-like curve, which is not what I want. actually no fit is fine, I only want a curve to show its varying.

The raw data was a 4000*1 array of radius, is there any other way to get a curve of the top of each bar of the histogram?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of automatically plotting a histogram using `hist`, you can get it to output the values:

```
[x, c] = hist(radius1,400);
```

`x` is the data in each bin, `c` the centre of each bin, so this replicates a histogram and then overplots a line on it (which will just connect the top of each bar so it may not look as smooth as you hoped):

```
bar(c,x);
hold on
plot(c,x,'r');
```

It is possible to use `fit` with an anonymous function as a custom model, but that may be overkill in this situation.